# How to separate value based on key in javascript?

Tags: javascript

This code is meant to print the action key value:

```
result [  
    { action: 'test' },
    { action: 'tests' },
    { action: 'tested' } 
];   
for (value = 0; value <= result.length; value ++) {
    response = this.actions[value]['action'];
    alert("Actions are: " + response); 
}
```

However, it causes an error: `action cannot be a read property`.

Answer (score 1):

the **actions** in your code is not defined,
try:

```
result =  [  {action: 'test'},
       {action: 'tests'},
       {action: 'tested'} ];  

for(value = 0; value <=result.length; value ++) {
    response = this.result[value]['action'];
   alert("Actions are: " +response); }
```